# Dummy coding omits / removes select variables from the data frame R

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, pca

I have a fairly large dataset **1460(n)x81(p)**. About 38 variables are numeric and rest are factors with levels ranging from 2-30. I am using dummy.data.frame from **[dummies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dummies/dummies.pdf)** package to encode the factor variables to run PCA.

However, as I run the following code:

`train_dummy <- dummy.data.frame(train, sep = ".", verbose = TRUE, all = TRUE)` some of the colums are from the original dataset are removed.

Link to original training dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

A number of columns from the original dataset including response variable SalePrice are being dropped. Any ideas/suggestions on what to try?